# Insert logo in header with html and CSS in python

Tags: python, html, css

I am converting my html code to pdf in Python and I cannot figure out how to insert a mini logo in the footer/header. Mainly I do not know how to insert the html tags to insert my image. I was searching to other posts in Stack but any was helpful for this case. Any help would be appreciated!

```
<html>
<head>
<style>


    h2 {
        text-align: center;
        font-family: Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
    }

    thead,
    tfoot {
    background-color: #3f87a6;
    color: #fff;
    }

    table { 
        margin-left: auto;
        margin-right: auto;
    }

    table, th, td {
        border: 2px solid black;
        border-collapse: collapse;
    }

    tr:nth-child(even) {
        background-color: #f2f2f2;
    }

    th, td {
        padding: 5px;
        text-align: center;
        font-family: Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
        font-size: 80%;
    }
    table tbody tr:hover {
        background-color: #e4f0f5;
    }
    .wide {
        width: 95%; 
    }

    result += '<h2> %s </h2>\n' % title
    if type(df) == pd.io.formats.style.Styler:
        result += df.render()
    else: 
        try:
          result += df.to_html(classes='wide', escape=False)
        except: #si son series conviértelo a dataframe
          result += df.to_frame().to_html(classes='wide', escape=False)

    result += '''
</body>
</html>
'''
    with open(filename, 'w') as f:
        f.write(result)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this will be helpful.

```css
/* Style the header with a grey background and some padding */
.header {
  overflow: hidden;
  background-color: #f1f1f1;
  padding: 20px 10px;
}

/* Style the header links */
.header a {
  float: left;
  color: black;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 12px;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 18px;
  line-height: 25px;
  border-radius: 4px;
}

/* Style the logo link (notice that we set the same value of line-height and font-size to prevent the header to increase when the font gets bigger */
.header a.logo {
  font-size: 25px;
  font-weight: bold;
}

/* Change the background color on mouse-over */
.header a:hover {
  background-color: #ddd;
  color: black;
}

/* Style the active/current link*/
.header a.active {
  background-color: dodgerblue;
  color: white;
}

/* Float the link section to the right */
.header-right {
  float: right;
}

/* Add media queries for responsiveness - when the screen is 500px wide or less, stack the links on top of each other */
@media screen and (max-width: 500px) {
  .header a {
    float: none;
    display: block;
    text-align: left;
  }
  .header-right {
    float: none;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="header">
  <a href="#default" class="logo">CompanyLogo</a>
  <div class="header-right">
    <a class="active" href="#home">Home</a>
    <a href="#contact">Contact</a>
    <a href="#about">About</a>
  </div>
</div>
```